# Seal Impreza Rear Bumper Crack

Tags: bumper, seal, plastic, cracking

About a year ago my 2016 manual transmission Impreza hatchback backed into another (parked) car and as a result the rear bumper has a small crack a few inches long with about a .25 inch separation between the edges.  I think the bumper is plastic, definitely not metal.

[image: View of bumper]

[image: Close-up of crack]

I don't care about the appearance and I'm not aware of any structural issue, so I did not replace the bumper.  But, I did think that I should seal it from insects and moisture so I've been putting duct tape over it (and you can see the adhesive residue from these multiple applications).

Unfortunately, duct tape has to be reapplied every few weeks/months.

Is there a better way to seal this crack?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to seal it, since that crack wont lead anywhere.  It doesn't give access to the car interior.  If you were to put your hand up behind the bumper you will probably be able to feel the other side of the crack.

The bumper will be made of plastic.  You may be able to warm that dented area up with a hair dryer and push the dent out from behind.  The crack may then close up.

You should be able to clean all that adhesive off with some white spirits without damaging the paint anymore.

If you really wanted to seal it, I would suggest using something like White [Tiger Seal](https://www.zoro.co.uk/shop/automotive/automotive-sealants-and-stop-leaks/tig-bw-tiger-seal-sealant-white-310ml/p/ZT1120753X?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=pla%2B%7C%2BAutomotive&utm_term=ZT1120753X&utm_medium=pla_css_2&targetid=aud-902363949563:pla-392746479006&loc_physical_ms=9046817&dev=c&gad=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwnMWkBhDLARIsAHBOftoLDJxkaiOMjIvCUaQGudCE0xh_5ewqqiErGaB7KsvBjvJlmnxE_d8aAnNHEALw_wcB).  It will fill the crack and it sticks very well, so wont peel off.  For such a small crack you would need so little of it however.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Can you give me some examples of "white spirits"?  (I'm not familiar with the term.)

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tetrion-TWH200-Twh200-Spirit-White/dp/B001DYO68Y/ref=sr_1_4?crid=4670DX8PJOH4&keywords=white%2Bspirit&qid=1687388182&sprefix=White%2B%2Caps%2C111&sr=8-4&th=1

Comment: I think it is called mineral spirits in the US.

Comment: Yes, here. in the US it is called mineral spirits.

Comment: Please excuse the tardiness of this reply.

Yes, using a hairdryer and Tiger Seal worked very well.  Thank you.